# Flash wmode opaque working slow on Facebook

Tags: flash, facebook, actionscript, embed, wmode

When setting wmode to "opaque" (or transparent) my flash app becomes slow on Facebook. I can particularly notice it when moving the mouse around (even on a tiny area of the screen), if I don't move the mouse then the slowdown doesn't seem to happen. Maybe its because its sending all events to facebook too?

When using wmode=window then it works fine.

The reason I want to use opaque is to be able to display Facebook overlays on top of it, and so the Facebook dropdown menu doesnt get hidden by the flash object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no solution. The wmodes other than window (default) are just terribly resource intensive. I don't know much about FB apps, but perhaps you could float the player above the content in a model window using jQuery or something?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But most Facebook games use opaque. So there might be a way to make it work better. Anyway, for now it was solved just by optimizing the code, so it runs at 30fps all the time at the moment (even in opaque mode). But still curious about exactly what causes the slowdown when opaque mode is used, which might probably lead to some more optimizations.

Comment: It's slow because flash player has to calculate what's going on with the browser beyond simple positioning. The only solution is to make your app faster like you said (optimizing code). Some computers are faster and won't see as much a performance hit. Just because you're seeing 30fps doesn't mean everyone else is.

Comment: We're testing it on several computers, and it works at 30fps on all (including a slow laptop with power saving mode on). What I'd really love to know is exactly what things can be done to minimize the slowdown when using opaque mode, if any, since we cant avoid using it.